# Group by query with max column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query the last chat messages grouped by chat partner of a certain user. My current query works, however it selects the user's own messages grouped by partner ordered by timestamp. But I want the last messages the other users sent to this certain user ordered by timestamp.

**Here is my fiddle:  [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10ce/1)**

Expected result: 2 rows

```
...    message
--------------------
...    r to me last
...    m to me last
```

I have prepared chat messages and the messages with the biggest timestamp are called "`x to me last`"

My current query is:

```
SELECT A.*, DU.user as username, DU.photo, DU.city, DU.year, DU.month, DU.day
            FROM db_chats A
            INNER JOIN (
               SELECT max(timestamp) ts, user, partner
               FROM db_chats
               GROUP BY  partner) T
              on A.timestamp=T.ts 
             and A.user=T.user
            LEFT JOIN  db_users DU on T.partner = DU.id 
            WHERE A.user = 'RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z' ORDER BY A.timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10ce/102/0) query to get the result:

```
select A.*, DU.user as username, DU.photo, DU.city, DU.year,
DU.month, DU.day from db_chats A, db_users DU where timestamp in
(select max(timestamp) from db_chats 
 where partner ="RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z" group by user)
 and  a.USER = DU.ID         
 order by timestamp desc
```

**EDIT**

The reason why your original query is not working is due to your inner join:

```
       SELECT max(timestamp) ts, user, partner
       FROM db_chats
       GROUP BY  partner
```

The result of this query is:

```
|         TS |                     USER |                  PARTNER |
|------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
| 1414453415 | xAlX66JQfmsOcotg00wPsZfx | RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z |
| 1414453387 | RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z | xAlX66JQfmsOcotg00wPsZfx |
| 1414443546 | RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z | YZQF4hbvyjbS0p7wYIR2Hkq9 |
```

if you check your db_chats table (below), In those time-stamps you can't find your demanded message. Hence the query will never return "r to me last"

```
|                     USER |                  PARTNER |      MESSAGE |  TIMESTAMP |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------|------------|
| xAlX66JQfmsOcotg00wPsZfx | RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z |      r to me | 1414443447 |
| YZQF4hbvyjbS0p7wYIR2Hkq9 | RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z |      m to me | 1414442845 |
| YZQF4hbvyjbS0p7wYIR2Hkq9 | RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z | m to me last | 1414453415 |
| RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z | xAlX66JQfmsOcotg00wPsZfx |      me to r | 1414453387 |
| RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z | YZQF4hbvyjbS0p7wYIR2Hkq9 |      me to m | 1414443546 |
| xAlX66JQfmsOcotg00wPsZfx | RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z | r to me last | 1414453234 |
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. WORKS PERFECTLY! I get the expected result, do you have the correct fiddle?

Comment: Click on ["this"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10ce/84/0) it's liked to the fiddle :) hehehe you're welcome.

Comment: But it does not order by timestamp desc?

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that one. [Here is the update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10ce/102/0)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of the query that you need. I haven 't add join to user table to fetch additional data for the user but I think this way  it 's more clear.

```
    SELECT  user, partner,message,MAX(timestamp)  FROM 
    (SELECT  user, partner,message,timestamp FROM db_chats ORDER BY timestamp DESC) DC
    WHERE partner = 'RGXiLkVpKGc4FSU7SeyMlZ7z'
    GROUP BY user,partner
```

The key is the sort order in the inner query before using MAX function for GROUP BY